# rails convert datetime to date within a scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

In my model I defined the following scope:

```
scope :today, -> { where time_start: Date.today }
```

This is not working because I'm comparing a mysql datetime against a date.
I am trying to do the equivalent of the date() mysql function (extracting a date from a datetime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :today, -> { where time_start: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day }
```

Using range in criteria will generate a `BETWEEN` query, something like this:

```
SELECT "models".* FROM "models"
    WHERE (
        "models"."time_start" BETWEEN
            '2016-07-29 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-07-29 23:59:59.999999'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Nic, I thought about this solution but it felt like a hack

Comment: This is in no way a hack. In fact, many would argue this is a Rails way of doing things as opposed to using raw and potentially vendor-specific strings in the query.

Comment: ooh great point! I will change the accepted answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As Nic Nilov suggested, that is one way of doing that.
Other way, you can do like:

```
scope :today, -> { where("date(time_start) = ?", Date.today) }
```

Resultant query would be:

> SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (date(time_start) = '2016-07-29')

Answer (score 0):

I've got a gem called [`by_star`](https://github.com/radar/by_star) which will let you do this without writing any code in your model.

This code:

```
User.today
```

Will fetch all users created within the current day. If you want to use `time_start` instead, do this:

```
User.today(field: :time_start)
```